# Shorter way of calling templated base function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I know the answer to this question might be simply "No" but I'm hoping that if it is "no" then I'll get a suggestion of doing thing differently.
Consider the following:

```
class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class IBar : public virtual IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void Bar1() = 0;
    virtual void Bar2() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class BaseFoo : public T
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "Common behavior Foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class BaseBar1 : public T
{
public:
    virtual void Bar1() override
    {
        std::cout << "Common behavior Bar1" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now in my class I want to use the base implementation for `Foo` and only in some conditions use the base implementation of `Bar1`. So naturally I inherit from `BaseFoo1<BaseBar1<IBar>>` and in my class's `Bar1` I will call the base sometimes (or even all the times if it made sense).

```
class MyClass : public BaseFoo<BaseBar1<IBar>>
{
public:
    void Bar1() override
    {
        if(SomeCondition())
        {
            std::cout << "MyClass Bar1" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            BaseFoo<BaseBar1<IBar>>::Bar1(); 
        }
    }
    void Bar2() override {}
    bool SomeCondition() { return false;}
};
```

What I'm interested in, is knowing if there is some way to shorten the call to the base function.
I considered using `decltype(this)` (or `std::decay<decltype(this)>`) and then I search for a way to use template metaprogramming to get the base type, but I couldn't find anything useful.

1 - Is there a way to shorten the call to the templated base?

2 - Any comments on the design?

I'm using C++11 in my project, but any suggestion up to C++17 would be nice.

Comment: `this->BaseFoo::Bar1()`?

Comment: `using base = BaseFoo<BaseBar1<IBar>>;` in `MyClass` definition. Then you can write `base::Bar1();`

Comment: @Igor thanks :) I didn't think of that, but still wandering if there is some way that the language can indicate base class type